# Custom scaling for discrete x axis and continuous y axis in ggplot2 scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having a dataframe like this

```
library(ggplot2)
ddft=data.frame(month = c("03-2012","04-2012","05-2012","06-2012","07-2012", "08-2012","09-2012","10-2012","11-2012","12-2012","02-2013","03-2013"), frqp = c("12.3", "11.4","44.1","11.3", "1.2","15.1","35.1","12","14.1","15.1","15.1","42.1"))
ddft$month <- factor(ddft$month, levels = ddft$month) #maintain X-axis order
ggplot(ddft, aes(x=month, y=frqp)) + geom_point()
```

How is it possible to scale y axis to show the highest no comma separate value example the highest value i 44.1% so make the number to be 45 and also some others numbers which dipicted in the y axis be without comma separation? Also for x axis how is possible to show only one time the 2012 and one time the 2013 but the dots in graph be the same as the are in the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version focuses on scales being proportional to the datapoints in a year. Panel spacing can be changed through 'x=unit change'.

```
library(ggplot2)
ddft=data.frame(month = c("03-2012","04-2012","05-2012","06-2012","07-2012", "08-2012","09-2012","10-2012","11-2012","12-2012","02-2013","03-2013"), frqp = c("12.3", "11.4","44.1","11.3", "1.2","15.1","35.1","12","14.1","15.1","15.1","42.1"))

lastfew <- function(x, n){
  x=as.character(x)
  substr(x, nchar(x)-n+1, nchar(x))
}

yearlabels=lastfew(ddft$month,4)

ddft$yearlabels=yearlabels

Frequency=as.numeric(as.character(ddft$frqp))

minima=as.integer(min(Frequency))-1
maxima=as.integer(max(Frequency))+1
step=5
ggplot(ddft, aes(x=month, y=Frequency))+  
geom_point() +
theme(legend.position="none",axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),panel.spacing.x=unit(0.03, "lines"),panel.grid.major = element_blank())+  
 scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(minima, maxima, step))+facet_wrap(~yearlabels,strip.position = "bottom",scales = "free_x")
```

[image: label merged and x_units]

Comment: Thank you. Please can you make an update to this answer providing all the step from the input until the end because I try to reproduce the answer using the input and what you made in the next answer but I receive errors.

Comment: Sure...edited with summary, hope it helps. Points are no longer sized by frequency as well.

Answer (score 1):

**For keeping only the year values (Scaling x-axis):**

1. Function to retain last n characters in a string

   ```
   lastfew <- function(x, n){
     x=as.character(x)
     substr(x, nchar(x)-n+1, nchar(x))
   }
   ```
2. Apply the function on the month column

   ```
    yearlabels=lastfew(ddft$month,4)
   ```
3. Create the plot

   ```
    ggplot(ddft, aes(x=month, y=frqp)) + geom_point(aes(size=frqp))+ theme(legend.position="none") + scale_x_discrete(labels= yearlabels)
   ```

[image]

**For scaling y-axis:**

```
Frequency=as.numeric(as.character(ddft$frqp))
minima=as.integer(min(Frequency))-1
maxima=as.integer(max(Frequency))+1
step=5
ggplot(ddft, aes(x=month, y=Frequency)) + geom_point(aes(size=Frequency))+ theme(legend.position="none") + scale_x_discrete(labels= yearlabels) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(minima, maxima, step))
```

[image: Output as desired]

Merge the labels into a strip:

```
ddft$yearlabels=yearlabels
ggplot(ddft, aes(x=month, y=Frequency)) + geom_point(aes(size=Frequency))+ theme(legend.position="none",axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),panel.spacing.x=unit(0.1, "lines"))  + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(minima, maxima, 5))+facet_wrap(~yearlabels,strip.position = "bottom")
```

[image: Label merge]

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. For the x axis I would like as it is but for the interpretetion of year I would like to have only once the 2012 and once 2013

Comment: Most welcome! let me know if the above is as per expectation.